# Get position of a value in a BST's inorder list(without creating the list)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am totally stuck on this problem. I need to output the position of a value in an inorder list (First index 0). The caveat is that I can't create the list and search through it. For each node I have a variable that contains information about how many nodes are in any given tree (including the root). I have it working for about 50% of the cases but the rest fail in hard to understand ways... If the value doesn't exist i need to return the index where it would have been.

In the class Tree

```
public int position(int val) {
    if (this.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }

    if (val == root.key){
        return (root.subNodes - root.rightchild.subNodes) - 1;
    }

    if (val < root.key){
        return root.position(0,root.subNodes - 1,val,root);
    } else {
        return (root.subNodes - root.rightchild.subNodes) +root.position(0,root.subNodes - 1,val,root.rightchild);
    }

}
```

In the class node

```
int position(int min, int max, int k, Node n){
    if (k == n.key){
        if (n.rightchild != null){
            return n.subNodes - (n.rightchild.subNodes);
        }
        return max;
    }
    if (n.rightchild == null && n.leftchild == null){
        return 1;
    }
    if (k < n.key){
        return position(min ,n.leftchild.subNodes - 1, k, n.leftchild);
    }

    if (k > n.key && n.rightchild != null){
        return position(n.subNodes - (n.rightchild.subNodes + 1), n.subNodes - 1, k, n.rightchild);
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Idea:**

You can do an in order traversal of the tree and keep track of the number of nodes you have visited. This requires a counter of some sort and probably a helper method.

We stop searching when we find a node with a value greater than or equal to the desired value. This is because we either found the index of the desired value or the index of where the desired value would go (the desired value wouldn't go in any earlier or later indexes). If we never find a node equal or greater than desired value, then the desired value would go at the end of the tree, which has a position equal to the count of nodes.

**The Implementation:**

Imagine you have this Node

```
public class Node {
   int value;
   Node leftChild;
   Node rightChild;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

And this Tree

```
public class Tree {
    Node root;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

Inside of Tree

```
public int position(int val) {
   positionHelper(val, root, 0);
}

public int positionHelper(int val, Node currentNode, int steps) {
   // In-order search checks left node, then current node, then right node
   if(currentNode.getLeftChild() != null) {
       steps = positionHelper(val, currentNode.getLeftChild(), steps++);
   }

   // We found the node or have already moved over the node, return current steps
   if(currentNode.getValue() >= val) {
       return steps;
   }

   // Next Node Index  
   steps++;

   if(currentNode.getRightChild() != null) {
       steps = positionHelper(val, currentNode.getRightChild(), steps++);
   }

   return steps;
}
```

Let me know if it has any issues or there are any questions